# Why is this DFA not accepted?

Tags: dfa

So I am supposed to construct a DFA that accepts sets of all strings over {0,1} of length 2:

So sigma = {0,1}

L = {00, 01, 10, 11}

What I initially tried was :

Why is it wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming B is final state, it can even accept string of length 1. Thats why. Add one more state to mark length 2 and it should be good.

A 0,1 B 0,1 (C) 0,1 D

( ) - accepted state

Also make sure anything more than length 3 results in non terminal state by adding a D.

Comment: Yep. I wish I could've drawn, but I'm on mobile and it's hard. Lol.

Comment: See my answer. Let your computer (=phone) draw for you...

Comment: Oh yeah, that's graphviz for you. Thanks @einpoklum, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the DFA you want:

[image]

This way, if another input symbol is present after the second one - you go from C to D and can never go back to an accepting state.

By the way, and perhaps more importantly - I didn't draw this image myself. I used graphviz, which is a neet tool you might use to visualize your DFAs. The code is:

```
digraph G {
  node [shape="circle"];
  Start [shape="none" label=""];
  C [shape="doublecircle"];
  Start -> A;
  A -> B [label="0,1"];
  B -> C [label="0,1"];
  C -> D [label="0,1"];
  D -> D [label="0,1"];
}
```

and there are online renderers even, like [this one](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/).

The "Start" node is a hack to get an arrow to point at the initial state of the DFA (this is why the image is centered on B despite there being 4 states).